Problem Capturing output of Google command in PowerShell
I am trying to use GAM (Google Account Management?) to get information in PowerShell. There is a command called 'whatis' that gives me this sort of output when run in the PS terminal...
PS C:\GamFolder> .\gam whatis gamdemo
gamdemo@domain.com is a user

User: gamdemo@domain.com
First Name: Gam
Last Name: Demo
.....

PS C:\GamFolder> .\gam whatis anotherdemo
anotherdemo@domain.com is a user alias

Alias Email: anotherdemo@domain.com
User Email: gamdemo@domain.com
...

PS C:\GamFolder> .\gam whatis demogroup
demogroup@domain.com is not a user...
demogroup@domain.com is not a user alias...
demogroup@domain.com is a group

Group Settings:
...

I've tried capturing the output by assigning it to a variable, and using Tee-Object and each time the important is/is not info at the top is output to the console and not captured by the variable.
For example:
PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo = .\gam whatis demogroup
demogroup@domain.com is not a user...
demogroup@domain.com is not a user alias...
demogroup@domain.com is a group

PS C:\GamFolder>
PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo

Group Settings:
....

I also tried redirecting stderr into stdout, but then the is/is not info just disappeared all together.
PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo = .\gam whatis demogroup 2>1
PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo

Group Settings:
...

Has anyone else run into something like tis before? Is there just something simple I'm missing?
Thank you.

2>&1 if you're redirecting standard error, or *>&1 for all of them

also $WhatIsInfo | Get-Member to see if the information you need might be in some other property\method

@sirtao it's not a powershell command so it won't have members

Thank you @js2010,
Your comment worked and it made me realize that I had missed the & when I first tried the command. I just tried '$WhatIsInfo = .\gam whatis demogroup 2>&1' and it worked perfectly.
Just in case anyone else stumbles upon this post with questions about 'gam whatis', I thought I would provide some examples of what the right command does.
PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo = .\gam whatis demogroup 2>&1
PS C:\GamFolder> 
PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo
.\gam : demogroup@domain.com is not a user...
At line:1 char:15
+ $WhatIsInfo = .\gam whatis demogroup 2>&1
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bo-l@prn.bc.ca is not a user...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

demogroup@domain.com is not a user alias...
demogroup@domain.com is a group

Group Settings:
...

PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo[0]
.\gam : demogroup@domain.com is not a user...
At line:1 char:15
+ $WhatIsInfo = .\gam whatis demogroup 2>&1
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bo-l@prn.bc.ca is not a user...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo[1]
demogroup@domain.com is not a user alias...
PS C:\GamFolder> $WhatIsInfo[2]
demogroup@domain.com is a group

Thank you all for your help.
